# Is it possible to display an image on the Windows console using the C programming lenguage?

Tags: c, windows, image, console

Want to know if it's any possible way to do it. I've been doing console programs since I started coding in C, and now this question has come to my head. I don't think it's possible. Any help will be great. I didn't tried anything yet.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not possible using only plain standard C, you need to use either OS-specific libraries or third-party libraries or frameworks. Also note that it's very different from doing console programming. There are plenty of books, tutorials and examples available.

Comment: By convention “console” implies text-based.

Comment: One simple-to-use library that can be used for displaying images etc is SDL2.